# rpi distribution -- initramfs or mount filesystem

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi

I have brought a `RPi`. Now which disribution to use from here `Raspbian` or other ?

What exactly is the diffrence between `Raspbian` & `other distribution`.

http://elinux.org/RPi_Distributions

These `zip` or `.gz` distribution files have `root` file system build into the `zImage` as `initramfs`?

Or `rootfilesystem` is a normal root file system, which gets mounted at boot time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> These zip or .gz distribution files have root file system build into the zImage as initramfs?

R-Pi distributions come in two fashions: SD-Card images, where the image contains a full "disk" image (partition table, partitions formatted with file systems in them and populated with a distribution). Or in the form of an archive, which can be unpacked onto the (mounted) file systems of a SD card the user usually has to prepare himself.

The standard Raspian distribution comes as a disk image. When unpacked you end up with a regular root file system, plus a boot partition for the R-Pi bootloader to work off.

Comment: you are saying "Or in the form of an archive,"  ... so this is only a root filesystem or Zimage also after unpacking  ??

Comment: filesystem is in which format .. jffs2,ext2/3/4 or ubifs format ??

Comment: @Katoch: If it's an archive it's a tarball (or similar) i.e. a collection of files. And with a SD-card image the file system used for root entirely depends on the choices of the person/team who created that image. It can be anything the Linux kernel supports.